# What is a suitable phrase for the situation?

Tags: phrase-requests

I had written it down last year, but couldn't find it or remember it.

The character has a very unique problem. So there are no previous solutions to it. The phrase I'm looking for might fit here

"What do I do? Not like anything like this had ever happened before"

Comment: "Breaking new ground" "entering uncharted waters" "shooting blind" "winging it"  Are these the types of things you're after?

Comment: What you're looking for isn't at all clear from the question you've asked. Can you provide a sample sentence with a blank space into which the phrase you're looking for would be inserted? (The current answers are wildly different from the previous comment—which indicates how differently everybody is interpreting your question.)

Comment: I've edited my question. Hopefully it's understandable now

Answer (score 1):

As a phrase, does "**without resort**" meet the criteria?

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/resort

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is [aphasia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia). Strictly speaking, this refers to the communication channels of speech and hearing, as opposed to the internal state of the mind, but in some situations the net effect would be not unlike your example.